# How can I hide the light blue bottom border on Web Part headers (on hover) and the border around the active Web Part?

Tags: css, branding

The bottom border only occurs on hover.  The active Web Part has a full border that I'd like to remove. I've tried the following styles to no avail:

```
.s4-wpActive 
{
    border: none;
}

tr.ms-WPHeader td
{
   border-color: transparent;
}

.ms-WPHeader, .ms-WPHeader td, .ms-fakewptitle , .s4-wpTopTable
{
    border-bottom:0px none transparent;
}

.ms-wpTdSpace, .ms-WPHeaderTd, .ms-WPHeaderTdMenu, .ms-WPHeader td
{
    border-bottom:0px none transparent;
    padding:0px;
}
```

[image: Hover to remove (highlighted)]
[image: Border to remove (highlighted)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

James, what Sig posted works for both things that you are looking for. The only change I would suggest would be to omit the use of !important in the style statements.  You want to try to avoid using that as much as possible.

```
/* Hide web part title border on hover */
.s4-wpcell:hover .ms-WPHeader td, 
.s4-wpActive .ms-WPHeader td, 
.s4-wpcell .ms-WPSelected .ms-WPHeader td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

/* Hide web part container border in edit mode */
.s4-wpActive .s4-wpTopTable, 
.s4-wpActive .ms-WPSelected {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following CSS worked for me.

To hide the active Web Part border:

```
.s4-wpActive .s4-wpTopTable, .s4-wpActive .ms-WPSelected 
{
    border: none !important;
}
```

To hide the Web Part title bottom border on hover:

```
.s4-wpActive .ms-WPHeader td, .s4-wpcell:hover .ms-WPHeader td
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
}
```

Note the use of `!important`, otherwise the SharePoint builtin JavaScript might override the changes.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed the active Web Part border.  Do you know how to get rid of the bottom border that only occurs when a user hovers over a Web Part?

Comment: See my updated answer